# Terminating Amazon EC2 - what happens to persistant data

Tags: amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

Its a pretty quick question - I have setup a pretty simple LAMP based website on EC2. I created an EBS and mounted it to the instance where I'm saving all the mysql data and other backups.

Now in order to connect to the instance - I use WINSCP and use the Elastic IP from where I can view all the data.

Now my question is - say I terminate the instance - the backup data and mysql data which resides on the EBS will still be available right. So how can I access this data.

I mean using WINSCP and the same Elastic IP, I wont be able to connect anymore as the instance is terminated - so how can access the data stored on EBS.

Sorry for the ignorant question but just starting to play with EC2
Thanks

Comment: You would have to start up a new instance, attach the EBS volume to it (and also the elastic IP if you want to) and then connect.  This is not a programming question, so does not belong on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you've created an EBS-backed instance and added to that (attached) a further EBS volume as a chunk of extra storage. In which case, when you terminate the instance, the boot EBS volume is released and deleted, but attached EBS storage is only released - it remains in the 'Available' state after the instance has been destroyed and its' data contents are left intact. You can then access whatever is on it by simply attaching it to another running instance.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that up - I was just thinking in one direction like how to access the EBS as it has no IP and the instance is terminated - and after reading your response I feel stupid -its obvious now that u create another instance and attach it. Just one other question - when I launched an instance, it automatically came with a 15 Gig volume - so apart from this I need to create another EBS volume for persisting data or is this one good enough - Thanks

Comment: If you want the data in an EBS volume to persist after instance termination, it must either be in a separate, attached EBS volume, or you must stop and snapshot your boot EBS volume (if you stored the data there) before terminating it.

Comment: Or if you want to retain the EBS volume of your EBS backed instance when you terminate it:                                                    ec2-modify-instance-attribute --block-device-mapping /dev/sda1=::false INSTANCEID

Comment: +1 Good point, I'd forgotten about the instance attribute setting.